# What is a transitive relation on set S

Tags: relations

MY answer: Given r,s,t$\in S$ a transitive relation on the set $S$ is when the elements $rRs$ and $sRt$ then $rRt$

i.e., $rRs\land sRt\rightarrow rRt$

Does my definition words correct?

Comment: Yes,it is. For example the relacion "$A$ is son of $B$" is not trannsitive.

Comment: @Piquito can you explain that?

Comment: If A is son of B and B is son of C then A is not son of C but grandson of C. Maybe you ask for explanation of transitivity not for my example. My English is something week, sorry I can't. No time for consulting traductor of Google.